# Reusing view controllers in Swift without hacked property

Tags: swift

I've been looking through a [Coordinator tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/158-coordinator-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started) and it brought up a problem with code I've written in the past.

Namely, when reusing a view controller I've used a property to be able to display different elements depending on which view controller the user arrived from. This is described in the above tutorial as a hack.

For example I segue to labelviewcontroller using

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "label" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! LabelViewController
        vc.originalVC = self
    }
}
```

and then on labelViewController have a property

```
var originalVC: ViewController?
```

which I then change the items in viewDidLoad() through

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if originalVC != nil {
        label.text = "came direct"
        imageView.isHidden = true
    }
    else {
        label.text = "button"
        imageView.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

I've a working example project here: https://github.com/stevencurtis/ReusibilityIssues

Now, I know the answer might be use the Coordinator tutorial, but is there any other method that I can use to simple reuse a viewController for two different circumstances, rather than using a property or is there anyway to clean this up to be acceptable practice?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that without passing originalVC just by checking parent type if you are pushing it inside a navigation controller like this :

```
if let p = parent {
        if p.isKind(of: OriginalViewController.self){
            //it pushed in navigation controller stack after OriginalViewController
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> but is there any other method that I can use to simple reuse a viewController for two different circumstances

If the "two different circumstances" you describe are very different (by this I mean "require very different lines of code to be run"), then you should create two different view controller classes, because otherwise you would be violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

If your "two different circumstances" are different, but also quite related, then you can just have all the information that the VC needs to know as properties. You certainly don't need a whole `ViewController`.

For example, if your `LabelViewController` will show a "foo" button only if it is presented by `ViewControllerFoo`.

You can add a `showFooButton` property in `LabelViewController`:

```
var showFooButton = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    fooButton.isHidden = !showFooButton
}
```

And then in `ViewControllerFoo.prepareForSegue`:

```
if segue.identifier == "label" {
    let vc = segue.destination as! LabelViewController
    vc.showFooButton = true
}
```

I wouldn't call this a hack. This is the recommenced way described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers) and they didn't call it a hack.